# Error when entering information into the database returns the last value loaded

Tags: javascript, html, button

Im working on a project that contains a discussion forum between users with real time updates.

Each message features a 'positive' and 'negative' button. When a button is clicked, I want to store the `id` of the message.

Instead, my code currently returns the `id` of the last message that was previously saved.

```
`var myVar = setInterval(LoadData, 2000);

http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function LoadData(){
$.ajax({
 url: 'view.php',
 type: "POST",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
  $('#MyTable div').empty();
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var commentId = data[i].iddisc;
    if(data[i].parent_comment == 0){

      var date = new Date(data[i].datePubli);
      var hourCycle = date.toLocaleString('es-ES', {hourCycle: 'h23' });

     //In the next line is the development of the positive button

     var row = $('<div class="info-box"><img src="./css/escudos/' + data[i].equipo + '.png" width="25px" height="25px" /><p>' + data[i].username + '</p><p id="date-p"> '+ hourCycle +'</p></div><div class="text-box"><p>' + data[i].post + '</p><div class="posneg"><form name="formpositivo" method="post"><input type="hidden" class="form-posi" name="posCommentid" value="' + commentId + '"><input type="button" id="positivo" name="positivo" class="suma" value="+"></form></div></div>');
    $('#record').append(row);
   }
 }
},
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
 alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
}
```

});
}`

```
`//Paso data
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '#positivo', function() {
    var posi = document.forms["formpositivo"]["posCommentid"].value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "positivo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              posi: posi,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                if(dataResult.statusCode==300){
                    alert(posi);
                }
            }
        });
});
```

});`

Document view

```
`include './database.php';
$data = array();
$sql = "SELECT *, discussion.id as iddisc, users.id as usersid FROM discussion INNER JOIN users ON discussion.id_user=users.id ORDER BY discussion.id desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch()){
    array_push($data, $row);
    array_push($data);
}

echo json_encode($data);
$conn = null;
exit();`
```

How can I change this code so that when I click on the corresponding button, the value of the `id` of the selected message gets returned instead?

Comment: The value of the id attribute must be unique within the HTML document. You are looping and assigning same id to the input button `positivo`. In this case the event handler will always pick the last element.

Comment: Yes, I understand that because the id being traversed in the 'while' is constantly repeated, I need to know how I can obtain that id @CodeThing

Comment: Traverse the DOM using JS - you can find the nearest sibling of that button which has the `name="posCommentid"` attribute. Then you'll know that's the input nearest to the button

Comment: Or, since it's all within a form, simply handle the "submit" event of the form instead of the "click" event of the button. Then you can [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form which will automatically get the correct input field and its data for you

Comment: Forms don't need `name` attributes, but if you changed it to, for example, `<form class="formpositivo" method="post"><input type="hidden" class="form-posi" name="posi" value="' + commentId + '">` then you could write in the JS as follows: `$(document).on('submit', '.formpositivo', function() { $.ajax({
            url: "positivo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment, the problem ocurred because you are using same id to multiple elements inside HTML page which is not recommended. To fix this, you can convert the id `positivo` to class or you can give any class to the input element on which you can attach event handler.

So your code in loop becomes.

```
var row = $('<div class="info-box"><img src="./css/escudos/' + data[i].equipo + '.png" width="25px" height="25px" /><p>' + data[i].username + '</p><p id="date-p"> ' + hourCycle + '</p></div><div class="text-box"><p>' + data[i].post + '</p><div class="posneg"><form name="formpositivo" method="post"><input type="hidden" class="form-posi" name="posCommentid" value="' + commentId + '"><input type="button" class="positivo suma" name="positivo" value="+"></form></div></div>');
$('#record').append(row);
```

Note here that i have changed id `positivo` to class `positivo`.

Now you can attach event handler like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '.positivo', function() {
    var posi = $(this).parent().find('[name="posCommentid"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "positivo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              posi: posi,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                if(dataResult.statusCode==300){
                    alert(posi);
                }
            }
        });
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem. I take your comment as a note to learn how to work in the future.